# Reindex site with http while waiting https certificate validation

Tags: google-search, https, security-certificate

I was unable to ask the renewal of an https certificate before its expiring date and now I have to wait 3-4 day for its validation.

When users find my site in Google Search, the link is with https, and they obviously get an error (ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED in Chrome).

Is there any kind of workaround to prevent this, and to make the http site reachable from Google?

The site is registered in the search console with the https url, it would be helpful to register it again with the http one?

Comment: 3-4 days? I know it's been a while and this has almost certainly been resolved, but I'll take a stab here and assume that you were getting an EV cert. Why not just get a DV cert in the interim? That will at least get the web site back to working order, and a DV cert can be obtained within minutes to (at most) hours. Then add a recurring item to your to-do list (or calendar) reminding you to renew the certificate 2-4 weeks before it expires. If you're entertaining the idea of making the website accessible over HTTP, then surely a DV cert isn't any *worse*.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you add some rewrite rules in .htaccess to redirect https to http

Then you can remove or reverse it and redirect http to https when your certificate is renewed.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I thought of that, then I was not sure it would work... does it get rejected before any redirect??

Comment: yes, this solution does not work -  without a valid certificate it is impossible to establish the ssl connection, the server does not receive any request (see also [this other question](http://serverfault.com/questions/429274/how-to-redirect-from-https-to-http-before-server-error) )